# How to access password-protected web service from chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am converting a Firefox extension to Chrome. This extension calls a password-protected web service. This web service is called frequently, every time the user performs certain actions within the extension.

How can the chrome extension call the web service without requiring the user to enter the password every time (or even often times) the service is called?

What the Firefox extension does is saving the password inside the firefox password manager, using the password SDK API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/passwords). The user only needs to enter the password the first time the service is called. After that the password is taken from the password manager. The user also has control over the password saving and can delete the password from the password manager at any time.

I understand that in Chrome extensions you can not access the password manager within an extension. Also, it is not possible in Chrome to store the password in the local storage, because the storage is not protected or encrypted in any way.

Are there proven solutions or patterns for developing such an extension accessing a password protected web service?

Comment: storage is protected from other apps, just not from someone physically snooping your machine.